# How can i get a specific image with python?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to get artwork of the day image from wwww.wikiart.org
I tried this code:

```
from urllib import request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import datetime as dt
import requests,os


def get_image():
    res=requests.get('https://www.wikiart.org/')
    soup=BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    image=soup.find('a',{'class':'cursor_zoom'}).find('img')
    link=image.get('src')
    return link

def download():
    link=get_image()
    file_name = dt.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    user = os.getenv('USER')
    path='/home/'+user+'/Pictures/ArtWallpapers'
    full_path=os.path.join(path,file_name)

    if not os.path.exists(path):
        os.mkdir(path)

    with open(full_path, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(request.urlopen(link).read())
    return full_path

def change_wall():
    full_path=download()
    os.system("/usr/bin/gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri file:///"+full_path)


change_wall()
```

Then I failed, it says "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'" What should i do in order to fix it?

Comment: *I want to change my wallpaper daily with these images

Comment: The "Artwork of the Day" changes on each page refresh. How do you know which one you want?

Comment: Regardless, the reason this isn't working is because the page populates itself with ajax calls, it doesn't include the image on original pageload

Comment: Yes, You are right. However, I think you understand what i want to do. Have you any advice to make real my idea or do you recommend any alternative sites which include the image on original pageload for artworks? Thank You.